# Unable to connect to internet with Ubuntu netbook

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection

I installed Ubuntu on a netbook; everything seems to work fine except for Internet connectivity.

I can connect to wireless network, but I am not able to see any web pages.

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: When you do ifconfig (or if that does not work, /sbin/ifconfig) in the shell, what is the output ?

Comment: try pinging: 1) your internet router 2) another device connected to your router (a smartphone or another PC) 3) some address on the internet. This will help you understand if it is a problem with your internet settings or with the connection between laptop and router. If you don't know the IP of your router, you'll find it in its user manual (mostly available online).  

Also post the chipset of your wireless card, there are some known issues with specific models. If you don't know what you have, post here the output of the command lsusb.

Answer (score 1):

To truly answer this question, you need to use the Terminal application - you need to do some testing to get further information before you can solve this problem.

In Ubuntu Desktop, the terminal is in the Accessories menu. Try these commands:

```
ping www.apple.com
```

If this works, it means that your connectivity to the Internet is fine. If you get no response, then DNS is probably your problem. If you get a line like this:

```
PING e3191.c.akamaiedge.net (69.192.221.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

and nothing happens, then your connectivity to the Internet is bad, even though DNS is working.

```
ifconfig -a
netstat -rn
```

These two commands provide further information about your system; it would be good to trap the listing and post it.